# p2p web application, terms and icons to distinguish caller from callee?

Tags: web-app, design-patterns, terminology

I'm working on a web application which uses web rtc.  Peers can connect to other peers.  The interface will change quite a bit depending on who is the caller vs. callee.

What are appropriate terms and/or icons to notify the current user whether they initiated the peer connection, or they answered an incoming peer connection?  I'd like to display prominently whether the current user is the initiator or receiver.

The application only allows two peers to connect at any given time.

Comment: Can you use a short phrase? "Your call to Mickey" and "Call from Looshi" are examples.

Comment: @JeromeR I could do that, however it's not really a 'call' like a phone call.  It's a more general connection that allows the peers to share files.

Comment: https://fontawesome.com/search?q=cloud%20upload&o=r

https://fontawesome.com/search?q=cloud%20download&o=r

Initiator / receiver seem appropriate terms?

Answer (score 0):

I think more information is required to answer the question, but since the application only allows two peers to connect at any given time, I still think that you already have a point of reference in that one part will be "You/Username" and the party will be the "Peer".

So I don't see the need to have a pair of terms to distinguish them, since you can identify yourself easily from the rest of the group (using icons or avatar or other visual elements/cues).

The problem to be solved is then how to indicate which party initiates the contact/connection, and that can be done quite easily by using either a directional element like an arrow, or a symbol placed over the party that initiates the contact.